# Elasticsearch: Results by closeness of numerical values in different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve:
I want to match people who have similar fitness level based on few parameters: push-up reps, pull-up reps and squats.

Let's say I have 100 athletes in my system, and I need to tell a user who's the closest to him by fitness level, basically who's doing as much pull-ups, push-ups and squats as the user.

Below is an example of what I got thus far from the docs.

**The part I have a problem with is** giving more "weight" to pull-ups value, meaning that a close match in pull-ups number is more important than match in squats.

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "pullups": {
                  "origin": "25",
                  "scale": "1"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "gauss": {
                "pushups": {
                  "origin": "56",
                  "scale": "2"
                }
              }
            },
            {
              "gauss": {
                "squats": {
                  "origin": "90",
                  "scale": "2"
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe using `decay` and the `scale` can get the job done, but I have a feeling that `weight` is Function Score is exactly what I need? maybe I'm wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What about boosting each field equally? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/query-time-boosting.html

Comment: @Yeikel I'm not sure how to integrate it with the example I have above, one of my major issues with ES is that I can't combine different techniques into one query properly :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. I only had to add the `weight` inside of each of the function scoring blocks:

```
{
    "query": {
        "function_score": {
          "functions": [
            {
              "gauss": {
                "pullups": {
                  "origin": "25",
                  "scale": "1"
                }
              },
              "weight": 2
            },
            {
              "gauss": {
                "pushups": {
                  "origin": "56",
                  "scale": "2"
                }
              },
              "weight": 2
            },
            {
              "gauss": {
                "squats": {
                  "origin": "90",
                  "scale": "2"
                }
              },
              "weight": 2
            }
          ],
          "score_mode": "multiply"
        }
    }
}
```